# Code adds another record instead of updating it

Tags: ms-access-2010

My program only has two buttons, namely to time in and time out.

But every time I try to update the record of the time out it adds another record to the table.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()

End Sub

Private Sub Command536_Click()

strSQL1 = "UPDATE BreakSked SET BreakSked.EndTime = '" & Me.Text412.Value & "',BreakSked.Duration = '" & durationz & "' " & vbCrLf & _
"WHERE (([BreakSked].[AgentID]='" & Me.List423.Value & "'));"
CurrentDb.Execute strSQL1
CurrentDb.Close
MsgBox "OK", vbOKOnly, "Added"

End Sub

Private Sub Command520_Click()

strSql = "INSERT INTO BreakSked (ShiftDate,AgentID,StartTime,Status) VALUES ('" & Me.Text373.Value & "', '" & Me.List423.Value & "', '" & Me.Text373.Value & "','" & Me.Page657.Caption & "')"

CurrentDb.Execute strSql
CurrentDb.Close

MsgBox "OK", vbOKOnly, "Added"


End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest renaming your buttons to start - something like `btnTimeIn` and `btnTImeOut`.  Much easier to remember what it does than `Command520`.  Just to make sure - is _Time Out_ attached to `Command536`?

Comment: I'd also _really, really, really_ suggest changing your SQL to the parameterized query that @HansUp suggested on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506453/update-sql-ms-access-2010)

Comment: I will in the future rename it those buttons.

Time in is Command520
Time out is Command536

Comment: Honestly speaking I do not understand parameterized queries as of yet that is why I cannot decode/understand that suggestion, copy + pasting what @HansUp did on my previous question gave me a runtime error 3061 so I went back to what I know.

Comment: If you insist on using concatenating for the SQL string, then implement my function [CSql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877395/vba-access-2016-update-query/48881020#48881020).

Comment: You removed the `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec` from your `Form_Load` event? It was in your previous question. Put a Breakpoint `F8` on the first `strSQL1 =` line in each command sub and then run your form and click on the TimeOut button to confirm events being called. `'Update` is not going to Insert a record

Comment: You say in your comments to answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51509850/2419128 of your last question that the Insert is adding records instead of Updating. You do know that's what an Insert does right? Was that a typo?

Comment: Are you're sure you're inserting and not updating? Both messages show the same text. ;)